# Fixed position div with adjusting heights relative to footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website which has two sidebars and a centre wrapper for the pages content. The side bars are going to have links which will jump the user to the relative part of the webpage. These sidebars have a fixed position so that it follows the user as they scroll down the page but when the user reaches the footer at the bottom of the page, I would like the sidebar heights to shrink so the footer doesn't block the links in those sidebars.

It's hard to explain exactly how the page is laid out so I have put my website into jsfiddle in it's basic form, link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MattBowker/e7ksg1ge/embedded/result/).

```
<div class="left">Lorem Ipsum ...</div>
<div class="centre">centre</div>
<div class="right">Lorem Ipsum ...</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

I would like to have a 20 pixel margin between the footer (in grey) and the sidebars (in red) at all times, and I haven't figured out how to get them to shrink in relation to the footer coming into the browser window.

Ideally I don't want to use JavaScript and keep the website using HTML and CSS primarily if possible.

Thanks in advance. Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
var spacing = 50;
var defaultHeight = $(".left").outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var calcHeight = $(".footer").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() - spacing;

  if (calcHeight < defaultHeight) {
    $(".left, .right").height(calcHeight);
  } else {
    $(".left, .right").height(defaultHeight);
  }

});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4ee62kc/)

Comment: I have had a look at your JSFiddle demo and all that's happening is the footer overlaps the sidebars, I want the sidebars to shrink in height so that the contents of those boxes aren't hidden behind the footer. I will use JS if it can't be done without it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Google Developers website is an example of how I would like the sidebars to work: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project

Comment: You should add JQuery and Javascript as tags in your question then :P

Comment: I have now, you happy? :P

Comment: can you help me? Like I have said I would like the sidebars to shrink, not just hidden behind the footer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use z-index or use javascript or jquery code.